# Scala serialization/deserialization of singleton object

Tags: scala, serialization, singleton, deserialization

I am quite new to the scala programming language, and I currently need to do the following. I have a signleton object like the following:

```
object MyObject extends Serializable {
    val map: HashMap[String, Int] = null
    val x: int = -1;
    val foo: String = ""
}
```

Now i want to avoid to have to serialize each field of this object separately, thus I was considering writing the whole object to a file, and then, in the next execution of the program, read the file and initialize the singleton object from there. Is there any way to do this?

Basically what I want is when the serialization file doesn't exist, those variables to be initialized to new structures, while when it exists, the fields to be initialized from the ones on the file. But I want to avoid having to serialize/deserialize every field manually...

UPDATE:

I had to use a custom deserializer as presented here: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2403, since i had issues with a custom class I use inside the HashMap as values.

UPDATE2:

Here is the code I use to serialize:

```
val store = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("foo"))) 
store.writeObject(MyData) 
store.close
```

And the code to deserialize (in a different file):

```
@transient private lazy val loadedData: MyTrait = {
    if(new File("foo").exists()) {
        val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("foo")) {
            override def resolveClass(desc: java.io.ObjectStreamClass): Class[_] = {
                try { Class.forName(desc.getName, false, getClass.getClassLoader) }
                catch { case ex: ClassNotFoundException => super.resolveClass(desc) }
            }
        }
        val obj = in.readObject().asInstanceOf[MyTrait] 
        in.close
        obj
    }
    else null
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: We'd love to see the question :)

Comment: Here it is :) For some reason it got posted before I finished writing it...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this for? Reading config files, perchance?

Comment: Basically, I am developing a system, and I want its main data structure to be written to a file for persistence reasons. The data structure will (eventually :)) become very large, and that is the reason I want to avoid having to serialize every field separately.

Comment: Side note: Avoid the use of `null` in Scala. It really only exists for interoperability with Java. Use `Option` instead if something can be "empty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No needs to serialize an object with only immutable fields (because the compiler will do it for you...)  I will assume that the object provides default values. Here is a way to do this:

Start by writing an trait with all the required fields:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def map: HashMap[String, Int]
  def x: Int
  def foo: String
}
```

Then write an object with the defaults:

```
object MyDefaults extends MyTrait {
  val map = Map()
  val x = -1
  val foo = 
}
```

Finally write an implementation unserializing data if it exists:

```
object MyData extends MyTrait {

  private lazy val loadedData: Option[MyTrait] = {
     if( /* filename exists */ ) Some( /*unserialize filename as MyTrait*/)
    else None
  }
  lazy val map = loadedData.getOrElse( MyDefault ).map
  lazy val x = loadedData.getOrElse( MyDefault ).x
  lazy val foo = loadedData.getOrElse( MyDefault ).foo

}
```

Comment: OK. I see your point. But is there any way to not use a factory method? e.g. I had in mind that whenever the MyDefaults is referenced, something similar to your apply method is called. Is this possible?

Comment: I rewrote the answer without the factory (using lazy loading variables).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I understand your solution, however, If i am doing everything right, it throws an java.lang.StackOverflowError. i guess when I deserialize, I call the same initialization again and again and again somehow... but I have no idea why! (Note that I had to change the getOrElse and the Option since I was getting compile errors to simple if conditions, and I had to use a custom deserializer -- for more details about the latter see the edit in my post)

Comment: @Y.K. 1. I did a small typo (`getOrEsle` instead of `getOrElse`) that I just fixed. The code with option must work now, if not show the error message. 2. If you serialize directly `MyData` using `Serializable` you should mark the `loadedData` field as `@transient` to avoid the infinite recursion serialisation.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. The error about getOrElse is as follows: ``value map is not a member of Option[MyTrait]''. And I still get the infinite recursion, even when i mark loadedData as Transient. I will add the code sample about how I serialize and deserialize in my original post right now. Let me know if you have any other ideas :-). Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the option code, which must work now. The serialization problem comes probably to the fact that an `object` keeps a reference to a singleton object containing the implementation. One possible fix is to use a custom serialization mechanism. But here the factory approach as shown before is a lot easier.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are saying I shouldn't serialize MyData but instead loadedData? Is this right?